# creating dynamic stylesheets in Stylus using Spine

Tags: javascript, spine.js, stylus

I would like to have the ability to haven different themes in my Spine application.
These themes consists of a set of colors and fonts.
These colors and fonts can be edited in a CMS.

I would like to know if it is possible to define variables in Stylus within Spine with the loaded data from the database. Or maybe create a dynamic stylesheet.

I tried requiring stylus inside Spine:

```
require('stylus')
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
uncaught exception: module stylus not found
http://localhost:9294/application.js
Line 4191
```

Is is possible to define Stylus variables in Spine?
And how do i require Stylus?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [spine.app](http://spinejs.com/docs/app).
It has build in stylus support and lets you serve node packages to the browser.